# Uncollective noun for Proration

Tags: collective-nouns

What is the uncollective noun for proration, which can be used with '**s**'?

```
people; collective noun
person; uncollective noun
```

The proration above can be used in such a context.

Ex. 
*Changing a subscription often results in a proration: a charge adjustment.
 So you can prepare your customer for any additional expense that comes with a plan change, we provide a method of previewing a proration.
 Alternatively, you can choose to disable proration.*

Comment: Can you please cite a definition for **proration**?  I am familiar with the verb "to prorate" but cannot find anything that is not legalese for the word **proration**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Proration*** is itself often used as a [count noun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count_noun) (what you call an "uncollective noun").

For example:

> Prorations are necessary to ensure that expenses are divided fairly between the seller and the buyer
>
> [*Modern Real Estate Practices in Ohio*, by Robert C. Kyle](https://books.google.com/books?id=3DQgvfwCDwkC&pg=PA411&dq=%22prorations%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi0wsnT25DRAhVl74MKHd9VCO04ChDoAQhIMAg#v=onepage&q=%22prorations%22&f=false)

An alternative is ***prorating***. But see this [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=proratings%2C%20prorations&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cproratings%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprorations%3B%2Cc0) for a comparison of the former with the latter. *Proration* is more common.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So you mean 'prorations' is  valid?

Comment: Yes, see here for examples (https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22prorations%22)